# Can the Cake Pattern be used for non-singleton style dependencies?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, robot-legs-problem

Most of the examples of the Cake Pattern I've come across appear to consider dependencies as singleton type services; where there is only one instance of each type in the final assembly of components. Is it possible to write a configuration that has more than one instance of a particular type, perhaps configured in different ways, when using the Cake Pattern for dependency injection?

Consider the following components. Generic HTTP service:

```
trait HttpService { def get(query:String):String }
trait HttpServiceComponent {
  val httpService:HttpService
  class HttpServiceImpl(address:String) extends HttpService {
    def get(query:String):String = ...
  }
}
```

Trade & Company services, that each depend on an HttpService, which may be different instances:

```
trait TradeService { def lastTrade(symbol:String):String }
trait TradeServiceComponent {
  this:HttpServiceComponent => // Depends on HttpService
  val tradeService:TradeService
  class TradeServiceImpl extends TradeService {
    def lastTrade(symbol:String):String =
      httpService.get("symbol=" + symbol)
  }
}

trait CompanyService { def getCompanySymbols(exchange:String):String }
trait CompanyServiceComponent {
  this:HttpServiceComponent =>  // Depends on different HttpService instance
  val companyService:CompanyService
  class CompanyServiceImpl extends CompanyService {
    def getCompanySymbols(exchange:String):String =
      httpService.get("exchange=" + exchange)
  }
}
```

Main app component that depends on Trade & Company services:

```
trait App { def run(exchange:String):Unit }
trait AppComponent {
  this:CompanyServiceComponent with TradeServiceComponent =>
  val app:App
  class AppImpl extends App {
    def run(exchange:String) =
      companyService.getCompanySymbols(exchange).split(",").foreach(sym => {
        val lastTrade = tradeService.lastTrade(sym)
        printf("Last trade for %s: %s".format(sym, lastTrade))
      })
  }
}
```

Is it possible to wire up the App so that its TradeService uses a HttpService that points to one address, and its CompanySerivce uses a different HttpService instance pointing to another address?

Answer (score 6):

As you can see from the answers (notably Daniel's, but also your own), it is possible, but it doesn't look elegant. The difficulty appears because when you use the Cake pattern, you mix all required traits into one object (using "with" keyword), and you cannot mix a trait more than once into one instance. That is how mixins work, and the Cake is based on them.

The fact you can force Cake to handle non-singleton dependencies doesn't mean you should do it. I would advise you to simply use plain-old constructor in such cases, that is where self-type annotation doesn't fit well:

```
trait HttpService { ... }

/* HttpServiceImpl has become a top-level class now,
 * as the Cake pattern adds no more value here.
 * In addition, trait HttpServiceComponent gets deleted */
class HttpServiceImpl(address:String) extends HttpService {
  ...
}

trait TradeService { def lastTrade(symbol:String):String }
trait TradeServiceComponent {
  // The dependency on HttpService is no longer declared as self-type
  val tradeService:TradeService
  // It is declared as a constructor parameter now
  class TradeServiceImpl(httpService: HttpService) extends TradeService {
    def lastTrade(symbol:String):String =
      httpService.get("symbol=" + symbol)
  }
}

trait CompanyService { def getCompanySymbols(exchange:String):String }
trait CompanyServiceComponent {
  // Again, self-type annotation deleted
  val companyService:CompanyService
  // Again, the dependency is declared as a constructor parameter
  class CompanyServiceImpl(httpService: HttpService) extends CompanyService {
    def getCompanySymbols(exchange:String):String =
      httpService.get("exchange=" + exchange)
  }
}
```

The App and AppComponent traits stay in their original form. Now you can use the all components in the following way:

```
object App {
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {
    val appAssembly = new AppComponent 
        with TradeServiceComponent
        with CompanyServiceComponent {
      // Note, that HttpServiceComponent it neither needed nor mixed-in now
      val tradeService = new TradeServiceImpl(
        new HttpServiceImpl("http://trades-r-us.com"))
      val companyService = new CompanyServiceImpl(
        new HttpServiceImpl("http://exchange-services.com"))
      val app = new AppImpl
    }
    appAssembly.app.run(args(0))
  }
}
```

Also, you may want do double-check if the Cake pattern is really best suited for your needs, as it is actually a complex pattern and dependency injection is only one part of it. If you use it only for DI, I would advise you to use a simpler solution. I've blogged about that [here](http://biased-and-fair-software-development.blogspot.com/2011/01/slicing-cake.html).

Answer (score 2):

Since each "client" may need a different implementation, you could just parameterize the service.

```
trait HttpService { def get(query:String):String }
trait HttpServiceComponent {
  def httpService(name: String):HttpService
  class HttpServiceImpl(address:String) extends HttpService {
    def get(query:String):String = ...
  }
}
```

To be used like this:

```
trait TradeService { def lastTrade(symbol:String):String }
trait TradeServiceComponent {
  this:HttpServiceComponent => // Depends on HttpService
  val tradeService:TradeService
  class TradeServiceImpl extends TradeService {
    def lastTrade(symbol:String):String =
      httpService("TradeService").get("symbol=" + symbol)
  }
}
```

The final mix would then do something like this:

```
trait AppComponent {
  this:CompanyServiceComponent with TradeServiceComponent =>
  val httpServices = Map( "TradeService"   -> new HttpServiceImpl("http://trades-r-us.com"),
                          "CompanyService" -> new HttpServiceImpl("http://exchange-services.com"))
  def httpService(name: String) = httpServices(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

This compiles and runs as expected, but it leaves a lot to be desired:

```
object App {
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {
    val tradeServiceAssembly = new TradeServiceComponent with HttpServiceComponent {
      val httpService = new HttpServiceImpl("http://trades-r-us.com")
      val tradeService = new TradeServiceImpl
    }
    val companyServiceAssembly = new CompanyServiceComponent with HttpServiceComponent {
      val httpService = new HttpServiceImpl("http://exchange-services.com")
      val companyService = new CompanyServiceImpl
    }
    val appAssembly = new AppComponent 
        with TradeServiceComponent
        with CompanyServiceComponent
        with HttpServiceComponent {
      lazy val httpService = error("Required for compilation but not used")
      val tradeService = tradeServiceAssembly.tradeService
      val companyService = companyServiceAssembly.companyService
      val app = new AppImpl
    }
    appAssembly.app.run(args(0))
  }
}
```