# How can I use Scala's cake pattern to implement robot legs?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, guice, cake-pattern, robot-legs-problem

My development makes extensive use of the robot legs binding problem.  I know [how to solve it](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) with `PrivateModule` in Guice, but it isn't clear how this would be done with Scala's cake pattern.

Could someone explain how this would be done, ideally with a concrete example based off of Jonas Boner's coffee example at the end of his [blog post](http://jonasboner.com/2008/10/06/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di.html)?  Maybe with a warmer that could be configured for left and right sides, injected with an orientation and a `def isRightSide`?

Answer (score 3):

Cake pattern doesn't solve this problem in its original form. You have [several choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190328/can-the-cake-pattern-be-used-for-non-singleton-style-dependencies/) how to deal with that. The solution I prefer is to create each "robot leg" by calling its constructor with appropriate parameter - [code](http://goo.gl/fZI89) shows that better, than words.

I think the answer cited above is more readable, but if you are already familiar with Jonas' example, here is how you'd make Warmer configurable with an orientation:

```
// =======================
// service interfaces
trait OnOffDeviceComponent {
  val onOff: OnOffDevice
  trait OnOffDevice {
    def on: Unit
    def off: Unit
  }
}
trait SensorDeviceComponent {
  val sensor: SensorDevice
  trait SensorDevice {
    def isCoffeePresent: Boolean
  }
}

// =======================
// service implementations
trait OnOffDeviceComponentImpl extends OnOffDeviceComponent {
  class Heater extends OnOffDevice {
    def on = println("heater.on")
    def off = println("heater.off")
  }
}
trait SensorDeviceComponentImpl extends SensorDeviceComponent {
  class PotSensor extends SensorDevice {
    def isCoffeePresent = true
  }
}
// =======================
// service declaring two dependencies that it wants injected
trait WarmerComponentImpl {
  this: SensorDeviceComponent with OnOffDeviceComponent =>

  // Note: Warmer's orientation is injected by constructor.
  // In the original Cake some mixed-in val/def would be used
  class Warmer(rightSide: Boolean) {
    def isRightSide = rightSide
    def trigger = {
      if (sensor.isCoffeePresent) onOff.on
      else onOff.off
    }
  }
}

// =======================
// instantiate the services in a module
object ComponentRegistry extends
  OnOffDeviceComponentImpl with
  SensorDeviceComponentImpl with
  WarmerComponentImpl {

  val onOff = new Heater
  val sensor = new PotSensor
  // Note: now we need to parametrize each particular Warmer
  // with its desired orientation
  val leftWarmer = new Warmer(rightSide = false)
  val rightWarmer = new Warmer(rightSide = true)
}

// =======================
val leftWarmer = ComponentRegistry.leftWarmer
leftWarmer.trigger
```